# Align SearchView hint with Toolbar title when expanded

Tags: android, material-design, searchview

I'm trying to implement an Material Design like `Toolbar` including a search (using the support `SearchView`).

I run into the problem that I can't get the SearchView start at the same position (72dp from the left border) as the title. It's some dp more right than the title. How can I fix this?

I put `contentInsetStart="72dp"` to the toolbar for getting the title at the mentioned line, but the SearchView now starts like 100dp from the left.

I want to have it like this: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right solution for my problem was setting `app:titleMarginStart="16dp"` for the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override `abc_dropdownitem_text_padding_left` to `0dp` or negative value using ref.xml. Default value is 8dp, when you add 72dp content inset this will move all content to right including their padding which contribute to those you see as 100dp.

Comment: After overriding this constant, there is still a little bit (maybe another 8dp) of a gap left. Do you have any idea which other variable is involved there?

Comment: @max.mustermann1 I'm not sure if there are anything else, but you can add negative padding until you adjust it to your needs.